# Pass an attribute of selected option of dropdown list as an arg to a function in 'onchange'

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

[image]

This dropdown list is AJAX response to another page. I want to pass 2 args in 'showStuds' function onchange. One arg is (this.value), the other has to be the 'sec' attribute of selected option.
I don't get why but

`onchange='showStuds((this.value),(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('sec')))'`

is not working.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your case is pointing to `window` object.

You don't actually have to pass the values here, you can access it inside the function as follows:

```
var select= document.getElementById('test1');
select.onchange = showStuds;

function showStuds(){
 var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
 var sec= select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('sec');
 alert(value+" "+sec);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wDzqb/)

*side note: avoid using `()` while assigning a handler function, the function will be directly executed when `()` is encountered and won't be executed afterwards...*